# Simplify android classes

Tags: android, xml, class, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm quite new to android programming and I made my first project yesterday, a cocktail bible app. It runs perfectly but the problem is I'v loaded loads of classes and xml's to store the cocktails data. I was just wondering is there any simpler methods I could use to do away with all my unsuitable classes of the cocktails. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Menu class

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[] = {"Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha", "Cosmopolitan", "Cuba_Libre", "Daiquiri", "Mai_Tai", "Manhattan", "Margarita", "Martini", "Mint_Julep", "Mojito", "Old_Fashoned", "Pina_Colada", "Screwdriver", "Singapore_Sling", "Tom_Collins", "Whiskey_Sour", "White_Russian"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cocktailType = classes[position];
        try{
            Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName("com.drunktxtapp." + cocktailType);
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Example of one of my cocktail classes. I have many of these.

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Bloody_Mary extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bloody_mary);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bYoutube);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Alt-ehDc3fc")));
                }
            }); 
    }
}
```

One of my xml's for which I have many for each cocktail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/beer"
    android:id="@+id/bloody_mary" >

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Bloody Mary"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bloodymary" />

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Ingredients"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="40ml vodka \n\ 120ml tomato juice \n\ 5ml lemon or lime juice \n\ 5ml worcestershire sauce \n\ 2 dashes tabasco \n\ salt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Preparation"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Squeeze the liquid out of the horseradish, then shake ingredients well with cracked ice in a chilled cocktail shaker, then strain into a Collins glass with 2 or 3 ice cubes in it; add a pinch of salt and a grind or two of fresh pepper, to taste. Garnish, if necessary, with a stalk of celery."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bYoutube"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="YouTube Clip"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My manifest with some parts removed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.drunktxtapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CocktailMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.drunktxtapp.CocktailMenu" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.drunktxtapp.Menu" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Bloody_Mary"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.drunktxtapp.Bloody_Mary" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need just one Activity and one xml Layout for all types of cocktails. (Assume that all cocktails has same layout, just the text and image are different.)

Instead of getting the class like your current approach, you will pass a parameter in the start intent.

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, CocktailDetailActivity.class);
ourIntent.putExtra("whichcocktail", "bloodymary");
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

In the destination activity's onCreate method ( Let's say CocktailDetailActivity):

```
// Get the param back
String cocktail = getIntent().getStringExtra("whichcocktail");
textView1.setText(cocktail);
```

Now you have "bloodymary" display on your textview.
In real life, you would want to pass an index to your database / array.
Then in CocktailDetailActivity, you will get the info by this index and display the correct cocktail.

Comment: So I have to add the intent you have given into the menu class and than make a standard cocktail class where I have set an img,txtview and button for a youtube clip then change the items with the second method you have given.Where would I implement the second method.

Comment: if you would be able to chat on skype my username is sean-dowling. It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The second piece of code should be placed in your standard cocktail class's onCreate method.

Comment: Hi in the CocktailActivity class how would I change the textview and image if I had a few items on the List??

Answer (score 1):

All you need is two activities (ListActivity and Activity to display Cocktail detail) & two xml layouts (one for each activity).

To work with this :

**1. Put all your cocktail images in drawable folder(set the name of images same as the cocktail name)**

**2. Start the cocktail activity when user selects an cocktail from list using Intent and pass the name of the cocktail as extra (or any other detail).**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, CocktailDetailActivity.class);
ourIntent.putExtra("cocktail_name","bloodymary");
startActivity(intent);
```

**3. In CocktailActivity's onCreate() method get the extras from intent object**

```
String cocktailName = getIntent().getStringExtra("cocktail_name");
textView1.setText(cocktailName);
```

**4.To set the image use the cocktailName value (if stored with same name)**

```
ImageView imgView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cocktailName));
```

Comment: Is it the same for the youtube clips too?

Comment: also in the try block does that mean I'm getting rid of this line of code : Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName("com.drunktxtapp." + cocktailType);

Comment: Since you will have only one activity for all cocktails there is no need Class.forName("com.drunktxtapp." + cocktailType); just pass the name of cocktail in intent extra

Comment: How will the program know when an item is clicked in the list so? I had the list Items set to the same as the class names so it would open it automatically

Comment: For you tube url make a map Map<String, String>  map = new HashMap<String , String>(); the first string is used as key and second is value. put each key as cocktail name and url as value.

Comment: If you are free to chat on skype it would be a great help my username is sean-dowling

Comment: for the line "ourIntent.putExtra("cocktail_name","bloodymary");" it only allows you to add two strings and I want to add like 20 types of cocktails, how would I manage this>

Comment: Hi in the CocktailActivity class how would I change the textview and image if I had a few items on the List??

Comment: If your free could you add me on skype to explain my username is sean-dowling